# How is a return / enter keypress encoded in a string sent to a SSH shell?

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, keycode

I am making a SSH client for a special device which does not have a return key on it's keyboard, my question is how is the return key encoded in the string sent to the shell? is it just '\n'?

Comment: do you mean the single character `\n`? yes. why would it be something else?

Comment: some different conventions exist... (im on Linux)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Then <kbd>Enter</kbd> key sends the character 13 = \015 = 0x0d = \r = ^M = CR ([carriage return](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return)). You can observe that by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd> in a terminal: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> tells the shell to insert the next character literally instead of interpreting it as a command.

You can select a different end-of-line character in [stty](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/utilities/stty.html) settings, but not all applications will notice. It's better to use the standard character.

For historical reasons, the character sent by the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key on keyboards is not the same character that indicates the end of a line in a text file: the end-of-line character is 10 = \012 = 0x0a = \n = ^J = LF ([line feed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_feed)).